# RegEx to Match Characters Directly Before Keyword and Directly Afterwards

Tags: regex, string, perl, match

I'm not good enough with RegEx yet. I've been searching around and trying to write my own, and haven't succeeded. I want to search through a string

```
Shelf-15-Contains(Item)10-Depo91
```

I want to search for (), which can be done by

```
/\(([^()]+)\)/g
```

When the RegEx finds () I want to grab the 'stuff' that comes right before the (), the () and everything inside, and then whatever follows directly afterwards. So,

```
Contains(Item)10
```

EDIT: Also, the RegEx I have above makes sure that there aren't nested (), so once I figure out how to match what comes before and after I should be able to run this recursively if there were multiple nested layers?

Comment: `([^\W]+\(\w+\)[^\W]+)`

Comment: fyi, the code posted by @l'L'l that doesn't handle `a(b)c(d)e`

Comment: @ikegami, It might if the last character class (eg. `[^\W]+`) is changed to something such as `[^-\n]+`

Comment: That would make things worse

Comment: @ikegami, https://regex101.com/r/zU0qH8/1

Comment: Like I said, that made things worse.  The only way you can get two matches is to use a lookahead (or lookbehind)

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
/([^-]+\([^()]+\)[^-]+)/g
```

Comment: Perfect! One last thing, what happens if the 10 after the item is left off and I sill want to copy the data "Contains(Item)"?

Comment: Sorry, one more question, this is implemented in Perl as $var =~ s/([^-+*\/]+\([^()]+\)[^-+*\/]+)//g; correct?

Comment: fyi, that doesn't handle `a(b)c(d)e`

Answer (score 1):

For matching before and after, use additional capturing groups:

```
while (
  $str
  =~ m/
        ([^-]*)          # before
        \( ( [^()]* ) \) # (in)
        (?= ([^-]*) )    # after
     /gx
) {
    my ($before, $in, $after) = ($1, $2, $3);
    ...
}
```

Nested constructs cannot be recognized by regular expressions in the strict sense (finite state machine accepting a string). Perl's regex engine offer additional constructions for recognizing balanced parentheses, but they are difficult rather to use.

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns gives examples how to parse balanced parentheses, at `(??{ code })` and `(?PARNO)`.

Finally, the structure of the string you want to parse seems to be a `-`-separated list. Try to find a formal grammar for what you want to parse, it will help you to design your program.

If you don't need to handle `a(b)c(d)e`, then you can simplify `(?= ([^-]*) )` to `([^-]*)`.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, no need to overcomplicate here. Here is a regex that will match `Contains`, everything in the brackets (with or without nested ones, balanced or not), and the optional digits. It assumes that there are `-`s around this construction:

```
\w+\(.*?\)\d*(?=-|$)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/rY5cR9/1)

Input:

```
Shelf-15-Contains(I(t)e(m))10-Depo91
Shelf-15-Contains(I(t)e(m))-Depo91
```

Matches:

```
Contains(I(t)e(m))10
Contains(I(t)e(m))
```